# Problem storing objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing on the iPhone and I'm missing something about storing objects in an NSMutableArray - what am I doing wrong and how should I approach this?

The relevant sections of the code are

I have an object, Entity, defined which inherits directly from NSObject. In my class GLView I wish to  define an array of these - so GLView.h

```
@interface GLView : UIView
{
    BOOL controllerSetup;

    // Entity etc - first development task it to get one up
    NSMutableArray *arrEntities;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *arrEntities;
```

and in the body in the drawView function - which is called multiple times by a timer event - I allocate the array and, for initial development, just one Entity object and add it to the array

```
- (void)drawView
{
    if(!controllerSetup) { // initialize on first call
        [controller setupView:self];
        controllerSetup = YES;

        arrEntities = [NSMutableArray array];

        Entity* thisEntity = [[Entity alloc] initEntity];   
        [arrEntities addObject:thisEntity];
    }
    Entity *entity = [arrEntities objectAtIndex:0];
    [entity tickEntity:0.1];
}
```

My understanding was that on the first call of `drawView` the NSMutableArray would be set up and the instance of Entity added to it, then in the body the a pointer to first copy of entity stored in the array retrieved and this manipulated (obviously I intend to add more and loop over them later).

However what happens it that on the first call of the procedure everything works fine, the `objectAtIndex` retrieves the entity pointer and all works.  However on the second call when `controllerSetup` is true and the initialization clause not executed `arrEntities` is empty and the program crashes as `objectAtIndex` retrieves nil.

So what am I doing wrong?  Why does my stored Entity object not persist in the NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try replacing the line you create arrEntities with the following:

```
arrEntities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then make sure to add it to a dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     [arrEntities release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

Basically, because you are not explicity allocating your array (you are using the static +array method), it is being autoreleased. Your program crashes when the array has been autoreleased and your code tries to access it.

One more thing:

```
Entity* thisEntity = [[Entity alloc] initEntity];   
[arrEntities addObject:thisEntity];
[thisEntity release]; // add this
```

If you don't release thisEntity, it will leak. addObject retains the passed object.

Answer (score -1):

```
Entity* thisEntity = [[Entity alloc] init];   
[arrEntities addObject:thisEntity];
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code. You need to explain what you've done. This is a poor answer.